# SQL server rank rows by group and condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with ranking of rows in one table.

```
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+-------+------+
| ID  | group | typeInGroup | rankOfType | score | Rank |
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+-------+------+
| 1   | a     | type1       |          1 |    40 |      |
| 2   | a     | type2       |          2 |    55 |      |
| 3   | a     | type1       |          1 |    20 |      |
| 4   | b     | type3       |          3 |    80 |      |
| 5   | b     | type2       |          2 |    60 |      |
| 6   | b     | type1       |          1 |    70 |      |
| 7   | b     | type1       |          1 |    70 |      |
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+-------+------+
```

I am basically looking for solution which would give me order for last column "Rank".

Each "group" has up to 9 "typeInGroup" which are ranked by 1-9 in column "rankOfTypes". Each "typeInGroup" has "score". When i am calculating last column "Rank" i look at the "score" and "rankOfType" column.

The row with the higgest score should be ranked first unless there is row with "rankOfType" column that has lower value and score that is <= 15 than the score we have been looking at. Order of rows with same "score" and "rankOfType" is not important.

I should do this check for every single row in group and in the end end with something like this:

```
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+-------+------+
| ID  | group | typeInGroup | rankOfType | score | Rank |
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+-------+------+
| 1   | a     | type1       |          1 |    40 |    1 |
| 2   | a     | type2       |          2 |    55 |    2 |
| 3   | a     | type1       |          1 |    20 |    3 |
| 4   | b     | type3       |          3 |    80 |    3 |
| 5   | b     | type2       |          2 |    60 |    4 |
| 6   | b     | type1       |          1 |    70 |    1 |
| 7   | b     | type1       |          1 |    70 |    2 |
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+-------+------+
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: can you explain how do you get the Rank for `group = a` ?

Comment: I look at "rankOfType". The lower the rankOfType is the more authentic score is. So i am looking at the "rankOfType" and "score". 
Row with id 1 has lower "rankOfType" value and score that gives result of <= 15 if we substract score from id 2 with score from row with id 1. That is why i rank row with id 1 as 1. 
Next we have row with id 2 and row with id 3. Row with id 3 has score which gives result > 15 when we try to substract row with id 2 with row with id 3. Since that is the case i rank row with id 2 as 2 and 3 as 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `CROSS APPLY` query, checks for any rows that meet your special requirement, if exists, than that row will have higher priority

try it out with larger data set and verify the result

```
declare @tbl table
(
    ID      int,
    Grp     char,
    typeInGrp   varchar(5),
    rankOfType  int,
    score       int
)

insert into @tbl select 1, 'a', 'type1', 1, 40
insert into @tbl select 2, 'a', 'type2', 2, 55
insert into @tbl select 3, 'a', 'type1', 1, 20
insert into @tbl select 4, 'b', 'type3', 3, 80
insert into @tbl select 5, 'b', 'type2', 2, 60
insert into @tbl select 6, 'b', 'type1', 1, 70
insert into @tbl select 7, 'b', 'type1', 1, 70

select  *,
    [rank]  = row_number() over (partition by Grp
                                     order by case when cnt > 0 then 1 else 2  end,
                                              score desc)
from    @tbl t
        cross apply
        (
            select  cnt     = count(*)
            from    @tbl x
            where   x.Grp       = t.Grp
            and x.ID        <> t.ID
            and x.rankOfType    > t.rankOfType
            and x.score - t.score   <= 15
        ) s
order by ID
```

Comment: Thank you ! This was the solution i was looking for :)